# Viewing a web servers file hierarchy

Tags: apache, http, web, filesystems

If I am on website `xyz.com`, how may I get a hierarchy of all the folders and files for that website, assuming that I have only the type of access necessary to view the files with a web browser?

For example how could I find out that `xyz.com/signup.html` exists, or `xyz.com/folder/` without being explicitly linked to them? The only way I could think of would be brute forcing filenames and testing for 404 errors, which would be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have full read privileges, I would consider looking into something like IntelliTamper.

Comment: By read privileges I meant "viewable with a browser". I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Ah yes, just press F12 in Google Chrome and click the sources tab.

Comment: It appears that there are a few other tools that call themselves "fuzzers" a program that can be obtained  via `apt-get` in my debian jessie distro calls itself `wapiti` and seems to do the job just fine with the command `wapiti http://website.net/ --scope domain --verbose 2`

The only way I found out about that was by reading about intellitamper, so thank you for getting me started.